# Get Cypress to resolve redirects before determining if the requested URL is a second unique domain

Tags: cypress

Let's assume I got `"baseURL" : "https://www.example.com"`.

I also have an htaccess redirect in place to 301 requests from http to https.

If I try to `cy.visit(/about)`, I will get:

> CypressError: cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a second unique domain.

I can't change the URL manually as it's being passed to Cypress as a results of parsing the site's navigation.

I understand that Cypress is trying to warn me that I am leaving the domain by switching protocol, which it should do as this could cause all sorts of session related issues.

However, since I am redirecting back into the right protocol I am looking for a way to tell Cypress to resolve the redirect before deciding if it should trigger the error.

I can work around the problem with a hack like checking the URL I am passing to `cy.visit()` matches the `baseURL` protocol but I'd prefer not to as this would then obscure issues such as the redirect being removed for whatever reason and users loosing their sessions as they move from https to http.

Comment: I can't reproduce this exactly as you explain it above. Likely, there is some info that it pertinent that hasn't been included. If I write a test in Cypress with baseUrl set to `https://example.cypress.io` and `cy.visit('http://example.cypress.io')`, Cypress shows the 301 redirect. I have some followup: 

1. What version of Cypress?
2. Are you visiting a production or `localhost` domain?
3. The intention of `baseUrl` is that you don't have to write the full url in a `cy.visit()`, so you can just exclude the base and write `cy.visit(/about)`. It will go to `baseUrl + '/about'`.

Comment: I'll double-check these next week after the holidays @JenniferShehane but off the top of my head: 1 - it was the newest available at the time of writing so 1.3 or 1.4 I believe. 2 - it's a production domain. 3 - this was a mistake when writing the post - I am indeed doing `cy.visit('/about')`. Also note that I have a workaround in which I wrap the `cy.visit` call into the `then` porttion of `cy.request` where I use the response object to get any redirect URL that may come up. That said if oyu cannot reproduce it let me poke at this some more next week to see if I overlooked somthing.